# left joining is returning syntax error on 'ON''

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 107
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.
```

I have a fairly large query and I am going to provide only a small portion of it. I am getting a syntax error on the `ON
    SplitAddresses.Client_id=d_client.CLIENT_ID`:

```
...
left join
(SELECT  distinct
   T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1,T.Client_id,
   Left(T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1, IsNull(SplitAddresses.Pos - 1, 2147483647)) Address1,
   Substring(T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1, SplitAddresses.Pos + 1, 2147483647) Address2
FROM

      d_client
    T 
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 NullIf(PatIndex(Delimiter, T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1), 0) Pos
      FROM (
         VALUES ('% Suite %'), ('% Ste %'), ('% Bldg %'), ('% Building %'), ('%#%')
      ) SplitAddresses (Delimiter)
      WHERE T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1 LIKE SplitAddresses.Delimiter 
      ORDER BY Pos
   ) SplitAddresses
on 
SplitAddresses.Client_id=d_client.CLIENT_ID


WHERE...
```

am i doing some obviously wrong with the syntax or is there a deeper problem? thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You should post the whole query. You are using the same aliases for the tables on multiple levels (`SplitAddresses` and `d_client`), so its not clear if you are doing that particular join correctly. But you are actually missing a `)` and an alias after `) SplitAddresses`. It should be something like this: `) SA ) SplitAddresses`

Comment: @Lamak thank you very much, can you please post as an answer wha tyou mean?

Comment: @Lamak your comment is the right answer to my question!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a reformatting of your SQL that might make it a bit more clear what your issue is:

```
left join
(
SELECT Distinct
    T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1,
    T.Client_id,
    Left(T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1, IsNull(SplitAddresses.Pos - 1, 2147483647)) Address1,
    Substring(T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1, SplitAddresses.Pos + 1, 2147483647) Address2
FROM
    d_client T 
        OUTER APPLY 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 
                NullIf(PatIndex(Delimiter, T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1), 0) Pos
            FROM 
            (
                VALUES 
                    ('% Suite %'), 
                    ('% Ste %'), 
                    ('% Bldg %'), 
                    ('% Building %'), 
                    ('%#%')
            ) SplitAddresses (Delimiter)
            WHERE 
                T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1 LIKE SplitAddresses.Delimiter 
            ORDER BY Pos
        ) SplitAddresses
on SplitAddresses.Client_id=d_client.CLIENT_ID
```

It looks like you are missing a second ) before SplitAddresses to make it:

```
left join
    (
    SELECT Distinct
        T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1,
        T.Client_id,
        Left(T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1, IsNull(SplitAddresses.Pos - 1, 2147483647)) Address1,
        Substring(T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1, SplitAddresses.Pos + 1, 2147483647) Address2
    FROM
        d_client T 
            OUTER APPLY 
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 
                    NullIf(PatIndex(Delimiter, T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1), 0) Pos
                FROM 
                (
                    VALUES 
                        ('% Suite %'), 
                        ('% Ste %'), 
                        ('% Bldg %'), 
                        ('% Building %'), 
                        ('%#%')
                ) SplitAddresses (Delimiter)
                WHERE 
                    T.MLIS_CLIENT_ADDRESS_1 LIKE SplitAddresses.Delimiter 
                ORDER BY Pos
            ) SA
    ) SplitAddresses
    on SplitAddresses.Client_id=d_client.CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Patience and the tab key :)  This is how I prefer formatting my SQL, it makes it much more readable and allows for easy analysis of nesting.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - I recommend you go to this link: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: @Lamak that appears to need valid SQL to format correctly, so it will not help him with the block of sql he has above.

Comment: @StefanH - That's right, but it's a good resource for the future :-). You should add an alias after the parenthesis of the `OUTER APPLY`. It should be something like this: `ORDER BY Pos ) SA ) SplitAddresses`. If you add that on your answer, @АртёмЦарионов can mark this as accepted (and gain an upvote from me)

Comment: @Lamak Updated, thanks for point that out.  Is the Alias strictly necessary though?  I rarely use Outer Apply's so I wasn't certain

Comment: Good thing you updated your answer, since it was already accepted. But now you have an upvote from me (and yes, it is necessary)

Comment: there's some kind of award for upvoted answers to downvoted questions hahaahha hope you get it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're giving `d_client` an alias of `T` and not using it in the `on` statement.

Comment: The alias is used in the nested select, I have to assume that the table is not aliased before the beginning of the Left join

Answer (score 1):

The ending parentheses before `on` ends the `outer apply`, not the `select` that you want to use it with. Add another ending parenthesis.